# Login and logout history in c#

Tags: c#

how can i make a login and logout history in c#

recording who's the username and the time and date in c#

Answer (score 4):

This would probably be best done with a new database table that records the username/id, the action (login/logout), and the time. Which each future action, your login/logout logic writes another entry to this table, saving it for future requests.